# Lightbox in Wordpress only for selected images

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, lightbox

I want to install a lightbox in my wordpress theme but select the images. If I install one of the common plugins, all of the images will be used with a lightbox, I want to set the images manually in the code..

What can you recommend?

Thanks

Comment: Lightbox shouldn't works for all images, just for them with specifi class or rel attribute. If plugin works as You describe, try to find place with DOM elements selector and change it.

Comment: I'd recommend using Thickbox, which is already built into Wordpress, all you have to do is wrap the images in an anchor with the correct href, read the [**codex**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/ThickBox)